# $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] issue

Tags: php

I'm currently learning PHP and from what I'm seeing `$_SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME'];` contains the current script's path. However, any page I try to identify shows up as "/index.php".

For example, I will run this on about.php, but the results return "/index.php".

```
<?php
    $current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    echo $current_file;
?>
```

Obviously I'm missing something, but I don't see what it is.

Comment: Yes, you are missing something, but I can't tell what from your information. Of course it always shows the called script, that is the name given in the URL.

Comment: is **about.php** a template file?

Comment: yes, it is a template file

Comment: @ProfessorB that is why. it is being included into index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your **about.php** is a template file that is at some point included in **index.php**, that is why you are getting `/index.php` as a result.

You should try using [`__FILE__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

> The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, __FILE__ always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your response, decker. The reason I am using is to have a form direct back to the page it was on once completed. `<form action="$current_file" method="POST">` with `$current_file = (__FILE__)` returns a url of the full path. Is there another way to return the user back to the original page without using the actual url? NOTE: This is for a login form, so I am giving users access to login on any page.

Comment: you could try `action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>"` or `action="?"` for the form's **action** attribute. Also, `action=""` works but I don't think it is valid HTML5.

Comment: Thanks, no action necessary (I did not know that). However, that did initially give me an issue - without the action, after signing in I had to refresh the page to get rid of the form. I simply did a header redirect to the referrer page upon complete and viola! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> 'SCRIPT_NAME' Contains the current script's path. This is useful for
>   pages which need to point to themselves. The __FILE__ constant
>   contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included)
>   file.

Excerpt from http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

The php.net website documentation is very verbose with some excellent user comments. I would suggest that be your first stop for almost any question you have about php.

Comment: You may want PHP_SELF `'PHP_SELF'
The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php. The __FILE__ constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.`

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's actually been the resource I've been using. I have tried `PHP_SELF` but still get the same results